# jQuery's .on() method combined with the submit event

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I've got a problem with `.on()`.
I have multiple form-elements (forms with `class="remember"`), also I add another one `form.remember` using AJAX.
So, I want it to handle submit event something like:

```
$('form.remember').on('submit',function(){...})
```

but form added with AJAX doesn't work with it.

Where is the problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: Try `$(document).on('submit','form.remember',function(){...})`

Comment: @Sergio replace `document` with the closest static parent.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

You need to delegate event to the document level

```
$(document).on('submit','form.remember',function(){
   // code
});
```

`$('form.remember').on('submit'` work same as `$('form.remember').submit(` but when you use `$(document).on('submit','form.remember'` then it will also work for the DOM added later.

Comment: Also bear in mind that `$(document).on` has much lower performance than `$('form.remember').on('submit'`. It now has to listen for **all** submit events in the document. It's much better to restrict the scope a little than listen `on` `document`, if possible

Comment: $('body').on('submit','form.remember',function(){
   // code
}); solved my problem

Comment: Even though @Liam is correct, $(document).on is still useful for CRUD operations on ajax rendered elements.

Answer (score 58):

I had a problem with the same symtoms.
In my case, it turned out that my submit function was missing the "return" statement.

For example:

```js
 $("#id_form").on("submit", function(){
   //Code: Action (like ajax...)
   return false;
 })
```

Comment: Note that `return false;` will not submit the form. For submitting the form use `return true;`.

Comment: If he uses ajax - submission will be done by ajax, later on 200 http status just will do intended activities. So return false will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the "on" is applied to all elements that exists AT THE TIME. When you create an element dynamically, you need to run the on again:

```
$('form').on('submit',doFormStuff);

createNewForm();

// re-attach to all forms
$('form').off('submit').on('submit',doFormStuff);
```

Since forms usually have names or IDs, you can just attach to the new form as well. If I'm creating a lot of dynamic stuff, I'll include a setup or bind function:

```
function bindItems(){
    $('form').off('submit').on('submit',doFormStuff); 
    $('button').off('click').on('click',doButtonStuff);
}
```

So then whenever you create something (buttons usually in my case), I just call bindItems to update everything on the page.

```
createNewButton();
bindItems();
```

I don't like using 'body' or document elements because with tabs and modals they tend to hang around and do things you don't expect. I always try to be as specific as possible unless its a simple 1 page project.

Comment: Not really. Rather use $(document).on('submit','form',function(e) {...}); Then no need to 'reattach'

Comment: I specifically said I don't like to do it on a global, document level. For a small, single page project this may be fine; but if you have a lot of different modules with their own forms global handlers create a lot of extra clicks and debugging problems if your code isn't targeted to specific forms.