# JQuery Doesn't execute on Form Submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have been reading dozens of threads on using jquery to submit an html form, and my form still wants to submit traditionally.  When I click on the button to submit the form, the php file successfully executes, but I get a page refresh, which tells me that my script isn't firing on form submission.  Any help?

EDIT:  A little more info; my form is dynamically loaded on the page, and is set to display:none when loaded.

My Form:

```
<div id='member-form' style="text-align: center; display: none;">
    <form id="addmemberform" method="post" action="/scripts/addmemberscript.php" style='margin: 0 auto;'>
        <th><h2 class="form-header">Add Team Member</h2></th>
        <tr><span class="error">* required field</span></tr>
        <fieldset id="team-info" class="team-info">
            <div class='label'>*First Name:</div><div class='label'>*Last Name:</div><div class='label'>Specialty:</div><div class='label'>Email:</div><div class='label'>Phone:</div>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="tmid" value="<?php echo $team; ?>"></input>

                <input type="text" name="fname" autocomplete="off" autofocus tabindex="1">

                <input type="text" name="lname" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2">

                <input type="text" name="specialty" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3">

                <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" tabindex="4">

                <input type="text" name="phone" autocomplete="off" tabindex="5">
            <div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="team-action">

            <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style='width: 70; heigt: 15; font-size: 14px;' tabindex="6"> 

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</br></br>
</div>
```

My JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).on('submit','#addmemberform',(function(e){
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr('action');
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    //if fails      
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
            e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
        });
    });

</script>
```

My php file:

```
<?php
$team = $_POST["tmid"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];


$con = mysql_connect('************', '******', '**********');
mysql_select_db(dbbmdmi);


if ($con) {
$sql = "SELECT First, Last, City, State FROM MemberAdmin WHERE   First='" .$fname. "' AND Last='" .$lname. "'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo'People found with that name.  Please choose the correct team member: <div>' .$row['First']. ' ' .$row['Last']. '  from ' .$row['City']. ', ' .$row['State'];
}

} else {
    $date = date(dmi);
    $name = substr($fname, 0, 1) . substr($lname, 0, 1);
    $inid = $name . $date;
    $memid = substr($team, 0, 3) . $name . date(d);

    $con = mysql_connect('dbbmdminet.ipagemysql.com', 'local', 'dbbmdmi');
    mysql_select_db(dbbmdmi);

    If ($con) {
    $sqlins1 = "INSERT INTO MemberAdmin". "(IndID, First, Last)". "VALUES ('$inid','$fname','$lname')";
    $sqlins2 = "INSERT INTO Members". "(MemberID, TeamID, IndID)". "VALUES ('$memid','$team','$inid')";
    mysql_query($sqlins1);
    mysql_query($sqlins2);

    echo 'Team member ' .$fname. ' ' .$lname. ' was successfully added.';
    }
}}


?>
```

Comment: Likely because you are referencing an id that the form doesn't have. Your submit says listen for an id but your form has the name attribute but no id attribute

Comment: Side note, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated, use pdo or `mysqli_`.

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks for the id catch, however it's still doing the same thing.  I know, I'm getting around to mysqli.

Comment: Is it loaded in my JavaScript? If so, you'll want to use `on('submit'` instead

Comment: If I'm following your question correctly, the form is loaded through an ajax call.

Comment: Also if it still doesn't work then make sure there are no console errors

Comment: Oh if you load the form into the page using JavaScript then you probably have to use the on('submit') for it to work

Comment: I tried .on('submit'), still nothing.  Checking console.

Comment: Unfortunately, no console errors.

Comment: This example is more what I meant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545941/jquery-on-submit-event

Comment: Tried  $(document).on('submit','#addnewmember',(function(e) {   but nothing.  Don't know what's going on here.

Comment: I am going to try it on my server and see if I can replicate the issue

Comment: Wait, what you have above is not right. You need `$(document).ready(function....etc.` then you need `$(document).on('submit','#addnewmember', function(e) {`...etc

Comment: Also you cause a syntax error if you do `(function(e)`, should just be `function(e)`

Comment: It's because your form ids don't match now. I was running into the same issue. You need what you have now but your form id and the jquery id have to be the same. You have one as `addnewmember` and the form as `addmemberform`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!  My weary eyes and brain are not seeing the little mistakes.