# Adding Google Analytics event to form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-analytics

I'm looking to add a Google Analytics event to a form that I can not access the inline html, so I can not add it as a `onClick=""` event straight to the html.

So my solution has been so far:

```
    $(function() {
  $(".form_submit input").on("click", function() {
    dataLayer.push({
      "event": "Kontakt",
      "eventCategory": "Submit",
      "eventAction": "Kirjuta meile",
      "eventLabel": "Kirjuta meile"
    });
  });
});
```

Althought this does not seem to work as clicking the submit button possibly stops all functions and refreshes the page.

How can I run the function before submit and then submit the form after? I've been suggested using `preventDefault();` and the after calling the submit again with `$('form').one('submit', ...` but have been unable to implement this due to lack of skill.

View site: http://avrame.com/en (the form is at the bottom of the page)

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Google tag manager? Your code seems to suggest do. Can you post screenshots of your associated tags and triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution ended up using this callback method:

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('.footer__contact form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  setTimeout(submitForm, 1000);

  var formSubmitted = false;

  function submitForm() {
    if (!formSubmitted) {
      formSubmitted = true;
      form.submit();
    }
  }

  ga('send', 'event', 'submit', 'Saada', 'Kirjuta meile', {
    hitCallback: submitForm
  });
});
```

Reference from: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#hitcallback

Answer (score 2):

You can actually push functions to `dataLayer`, and it will be executed after the first event.

I would do

- delegate the submit watch event to document level (see [Jquery .on() submit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545941/jquery-on-submit-event))
- intercept the first submit, pushing event and preventing default behavior
- and insert a function inside `dataLayer`, which submits the form again, but this time it won't be halted

The code:

```
window.submitGA = false;
$(function() {
  $(document).on('submit','.form_submit',function(event){
    if (!window.submitGA)
    {
      window.submitGA = true;
      dataLayer.push({
        "event": "Kontakt",
        "eventCategory": "Submit",
        "eventAction": "Kirjuta meile",
        "eventLabel": "Kirjuta meile"
      });
      dataLayer.push(function(){
        $('.form_submit').submit();
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I applied your code but unfortunately no events show up in GA. I added some console.logs to the code but these do not go through either.

Comment: Did you set up a universal analytics tag for `event:Kontakt`?